# How to Call same class in class function to instance functionin swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have one class in there are 2 methods first is `class` method and another is normal method and i want to called 2nd method call from `class` method, i have try many code but still i'm not getting solutions please guide me and help.

```
class ClassTest : NSObject
{
    class func SentByUserString() -> String
    {
        // i want call here to sample method
        return "hello"
    }

    func  sample() -> Void
    {
        print("Sample Method Called")
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call an instance method without an instance to call it on.

Comment: @Thilo , ok but any other way to called or not ?

Comment: @Thilo, here i'm calling instance method to another instance method but i'm facing issue in instance method called from Class method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create static instance of that class and then call that method from that class function using that static instance. Change your code something like this

```
class ClassTest : NSObject {

    struct Static {
        static var instance: ClassTest?
    }

    class func sharedManager() -> ClassTest {
        if (Static.instance == nil)
        {
            Static.instance = ClassTest()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    class func SentByUserString() -> String {
        // now call here your sample method like this
        Static.instance?.sample()
        return "hello"
    }

    func  sample() -> Void {
        print("Sample Method Called")
    }
}
```

Comment: i have implement Ur code but still sample method does not called ..Plz help, if ur code work then definitely i will accept Ur answer...

Comment: @AkshayDegada You need to call `SentByUserString` like this way `ClassTest.SentByUserString()` then it will call `sample` method that is inside that method.

Comment: i know about SentByUserString but i'm facing issue in sample() method from SendByUserString Method.

Comment: First of all initialized your static instance by calling this method `ClassTest .sharedManager()` then call `ClassTest.SentByUserString()` It will work perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118515/discussion-between-akshay-degada-and-nirav).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really something you should be doing, but you can just make an instance of the class in that method, and call the sample method on that instance.

```
class func SentByUserString() -> String {
        let temp = ClassTest()
        temp.sample()
        return "hello"
}
```